# want to search by integer value in mongoDB regex

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a collection `{mobile:123456789},{mobile:8877887799},{mobile:8899445588}`so here i want to search patter to get matched field.

```
db.users.find({"$or":[{"mobile":/^88.*/}]}) if i did this code to search and want to get matched field "two". how can i do this.
```

Comment: regex pattern matching strings in queries. Not number...

Comment: Then you're plain out of luck, since regular expressions only works on "strings", and **everywhere**. JavaScript stringifies when subjected to a regex test. So you could always use `$where`, but it's not efficient and basically scans the whole collection.

Comment: any other option to get efficient integer search

Comment: db.users.find({ $where: "/^902.*/.users(this.mobile)" })
error: {
        "$err" : "TypeError: Object /^902.*/ has no method 'users' near 's.mobile)' ",
        "code" : 16722
}

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments. `$where` runs JavaScript code. Read up on how to write JavaScript and perform regular expression matches.

Comment: If those are phone numbers, they should not be stored as integers in the first place.

Comment: `db.users.find({ $where: function() { return !!('' + this.mobile).match(/^88.*/im) } });` You can use something like that

Comment: ok this runs perfectly          db.users.find({$where:"/90.*/.test(this.mobile)"})

Comment: Alexandru your answer also works for me